# Understand SQS visibility timeout with multiple pollers

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I've read in multiple places that sqs use of minimum 5 pollers simultaneously to pull messages from queue. So if there's aren't sufficient available consumers (I'm using lambdas), then a message will be throttled and get back to the queue. And It's therefor recommended to set visibility timeout 6 times of the process time (Or lambda timeout). The thing that i fail to understand - When there's polling of a message from the queue without available consumer - During that visibilityTimeout window will the message still be assigned to a consumer that gets available? Or once throttled it gets back to the queue right away. I just fail to understand the entire logic behind visibilityTimeout configuration had would appreciate explanation in this matter. If I need that a message that was pulled from queue but no availble consumer to take it at the moment- How can i set it to be back to be picked straight away? This is not a Fifo queue. Thanks

I can see i have throttled messages and not sure if im configured properly (Im with concurrency of 12, lambda timeout set to 60 and visibilityTimeout also 60 right now)

Comment: The key here is the lambda service polling from SQS, that one is responsible for receiving the message, trying to invoke a lambda with it and then retaining the message if the lambda is currently throttled, retrying the invocation 5 more times. You cannot change that behaviour and neither should it matter. If you misconfigure the visibility timeout you end up with the lambda service buffering messages that were throttled and those same message becoming available in the queue again potentially being picked up more times and triggering another lambda invocation.

Comment: @luk2302
Let me see if i understand.
Is the visibilityTimeout the duration of the lambda service retaining the msg and retrying to find an available consumer? In what intervals?
And is it always retrying for 5 times?

I configured the sqs to 1:1 lambda timeout and got a few of 'ApproximateReceiveCount': '2' (Which is bad for me), but when increasing the visibility to 5 times the timeout i don't get any. How is that? Is it because during the increasing of the visibility the lambda service was able to retry more/longer intervals?
Thanks alot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lambda service gets the message(s) from the queue and then tries to invoke a lambda function with that message. There are couple of things that can happen:

- lambda accepts the message, processes it and succeeds -> lambda service attempts to delete message from queue
- lambda accepts the message, fails to process it -> lambda service discards the message, after the visibility timeout expires the message becomes visible again, **no** retries by the lambda service in this case.
- lambda rejects the message due to throttling -> lambda service will retry the message after "lambda timeout" seconds, up to 5 such retry attempts happen

Because you cannot know if your lambda will ever be throttled you must assume it will be throttled, therefore you must ensure that even the 5 retires and a potential execution in the last retry all happen within the configured visibility timeout: therefore visibility timeout = 6 * lambda timeout.

If you incorrectly configure the visibility timeout the message might become visible while the lambda (service) is already / still working on it leading to multiple executions of the same message.

Comment: Thanks again, you helped alot!
So another question - The retry mechanism is automatically happening?
What happens if I decide to set visibility to same as lambda timeout? 
The msg will be back in the queue, but the lambda service holding the msg wills still retry to assign a function after the lambda timeout? So it might follow to duplicate processing?

Comment: @OrelPechter yes, automatically, and yes, duplicate procesing.

Comment: @luk2303 Will the 'ApproximateFirstReceiveTimestamp' param in messageAttribute specify the time the lambda service pulls the message from the queue or the time the message was assigned to an available lambda function?

Comment: @OrelPechter as the name suggests I would expect it to be from the moment of the ReceiveMessage, unrelated to any indication of your target lambda. SQS sets that attribute and does not even know of any lambda functions triggering.

Comment: @luk2302 is there any official AWS doc regarding this statement "lambda service will retry the message after "lambda timeout" seconds, up to 5 such retry attempts happen" ?

Comment: @JohnDoe not explicitly, at least not that I am aware of. The docs only state to configure the visibility timeout as high as 6 times the lambda timeout and I had some talks with one AWS employee about this. You can obviously test this by creating a lambda, limiting the concurrency to 1 and then submitting messages into the queue and checking when the throttles happen and how often.